# Mean of n-dimensional uniform unit-ball

Tags: expected-value, marginal-distribution

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional unit-ball:

$$ \{(t_1,...,t_n) : t_1^2+...+t_n^2\le1\}
$$

And suppose I have an $n$-dimensional random variable $(X_1,...,X_n)$ who distributes uniform in this unit-ball. How do I find the marginal expectation of $\mathbb E[X_i]$?

I know it's $0$, by "symmetry", but am looking for a more formal proof.

Comment: Can you write down the corresponding integral and use that the integrand is radially symmetric?

Comment: That would be also "by symmetry", but at the same time more formal.

Comment: What I would want is to somehow find the the cdf of the $X_i$, then show it's the same for $-X_i$. Hence by the tail formula of expectation, the expectation is the same.
Another possibility is to find the pdf, and somehow use it in the integral for the expectation. 
Problem is the integrals are quite hard... :-\

Comment: @Ramanujan I'm kind of stuck... I mean, suppose we take  $X_1$ - then the expectation for it using PDF is: $ \int_{x_1=-1}^1 x_1\cdot\int_{x_2=-\sqrt{1-x_1^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x_1^2}} ... \int_{x_n=-\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2}}^{\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2}} dx_n...dx_2 dx_1 $, where everything after $x_1$ and up to $dx_1$ is the marginal PDF of $X_1$.

Comment: If you now preform the variable change $\tilde{x_n} = - x_n$ in the innermost integral, you should get that nothing changes.